# UnknownError: angular is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, element

I am trying to capture a text field in my protractor test. I am using

```
element(by.model('["newTag.text"]'));
```

When I run the test I get this error:

```
UnknownError: angular is not defined Build info: version: '2.44.0',
revision: '76d78cf', time: '2014-10-23 20:02:37' System info: host:
'USPDXL540', ip: '10.10.134.32', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch:
'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_01' Driver info:
driver.version: unknown
```

Comment: Your system info has nothing to do with this question. It simply means that there is no variable named `angular` wherever you are trying to use this `angular`.

Comment: What variable do i need pass in that ?

Answer (score 0):

This generally happens when angularjs script is not loaded or some application that has dependency on angularjs is not able to find it. Try loading angularjs as the first script.